# Calling OAuth protected API in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to call https://developers.amadeus.com/ API. I got mine API key and secret. When i create GET request at their web page i get my access token for that call. Now if I got this correctly I need to use that token to access that GET call. I used Postman to test that and its correct. Providing URL and access token creates JSON response from their server.

Now I want to replicate that in my .NET Core web application.

I use this `HttpClientExtensions` class to make a call to API.

```
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<TResponse> GetFromJsonAsync<TResponse>(this HttpClient client, string url)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(content);
    }
}
```

This is my `HomeController` and its `Index` method:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var model = client.GetFromJsonAsync<Flight>("https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2").Result;
            return View(model);
        }
```

To use access token I have read around the Google that I need to setup AuthenticationScheme. I dont know anything about all of this as I started to learn API's about a day ago.
I stumbled upon this guide [ASP.NET Core Token Authentication](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5160941/ASP-NET-CORE-Token-Authentication-and-Authorizatio#Middleware) and will try with that next.

I would appreciate if someone could help me a bit or explain this stuff to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it work in Postman, you can use its built-in feature to generate code, to get some hints about how you should implement it in C#.

See this link [Generate code snippets in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/)